Python cannot write mouse coordinates to self.label in a different function in the same class. Why is that function not recognising that label?
#! /usr/bin/env python3
#  -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# GUI module generated by PAGE version 8.0
#  in conjunction with Tcl version 8.6
#    Apr 23, 2024 11:05:03 PM CEST  platform: Windows NT

import sys
import os.path
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter.constants import *
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from pynput import mouse
#import win32api, win32con
#import pyHook3 as pyHook
import pyWinhook as pyHook
import pythoncom
#import pyautogui 
#from pyautgui import mouse

_location = os.path.dirname(__file__)

import BRC_ASSISTCURSOR_TEST2_support

_bgcolor = '#d9d9d9'
_fgcolor = '#000000'
_tabfg1 = 'black' 
_tabfg2 = 'white' 
_bgmode = 'light' 
_tabbg1 = '#d9d9d9' 
_tabbg2 = 'gray40'

mdx=-1 , mdy=-1
class mouse_data:
    
    def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
        global mdx ,  global mdy
        if pressed and button == mouse.Button.middle:
                print("middle mouseclick: " + "X:" + str(x) + " y: "+ str(y))
                mdx = x ,  mdy = y 
                Toplevel1.show_mousepos("")   #invoke function from Toplevel1 class

    #---start pynput Listener -----------------------------    
    mouselistener = mouse.Listener(on_click = on_click)
    mouselistener.start() 
   
class Toplevel1:
   
    def show_mousepos(self):   #>to write mdx, mdy in class Toplevel1 label['text']
        print("mdx:"+ str(mdx) + " mdy:"+str(mdy))  #--ok > mdx and mdy as globals are seen
        self.lbl2['text'] = str(mdy)  
        #>gives--AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'lbl2'

        #-or 
        self.lbl2.configure(text = str(mdy))
        #>gives--AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'lbl2'

    #--Why does this function not recognize self.label as in btnxy_click ??
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------                
    
    def btnxy_click(self):
        self.lbl2['text'] = "XY CLICK LABEL2"
        
    def btnstop_click(self):
        exit()
             
    def __init__(self, top=None):
        #..This class configures and populates the toplevel window.
        #..top is the toplevel containing window
        top.geometry("618x308+597+9")
        top.minsize(120, 1)
        top.maxsize(1924, 1576)
        top.resizable(1,  1)
        top.title("BRICSCAD ASSIST COORDINATEN")        

        self.top = top
        
        self.lbl2 = tk.Label(self.top)
        self.lbl2.place(relx=0.049, rely=0.227, height=30, width=125)
        self.lbl2.configure(text='''Label2''')
                  
        self.btnXY = tk.Button(self.top)
        self.btnXY.place(relx=0.89, rely=0.091, height=26, width=57)
        self.btnXY.configure(text='''XY''')
        self.btnXY.configure(command = self.btnxy_click)
           
        self.btnStop = tk.Button(self.top)
        self.btnStop.configure(text="STOP")
        self.btnStop.place(relx=0.89, rely=0.841, height=26, width=57)
        self.btnStop.configure(command = self.btnstop_click)
 
def start_up():
    BRC_ASSISTCURSOR_TEST2_support.main()
   
if __name__ == '__main__':
    BRC_ASSISTCURSOR_TEST2_support.main()

#######################################################
### ADDED THE BRC_ASSISTCURSOR_support.py file code ###
#######################################################
#! /usr/bin/env python3
#  -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
# Support module generated by PAGE version 8.0
#  in conjunction with Tcl version 8.6
#    Apr 23, 2024 11:05:22 PM CEST  platform: Windows NT

import sys
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter.constants import *

import BRC_ASSISTCURSOR_TEST2

_debug = True # False to eliminate debug printing from callback functions.

def main(*args):
    '''Main entry point for the application.'''
    global root
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.protocol( 'WM_DELETE_WINDOW' , root.destroy)
    # Creates a toplevel widget.
    global _top1, _w1
    _top1 = root
    _w1 = BRC_ASSISTCURSOR_TEST2.Toplevel1(_top1)
    root.mainloop()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    BRC_ASSISTCURSOR_TEST2.start_up()

(I left only the necessary lines, used PAGE to build the gui.)
Added all the necessary code to let it run with the BRC-ASSISTCURSOR_support.py file
Runs fine, gui top frame appears, btnxy_click changes lbl2 text.
Mouse middle click works and shows x,y coordinates with print command in the editor.
However I do not find a way to have these coordinates shown in the lbl2 label
As a newbie I do not understand what is happening although the functions and label
are in the same Toplevel1 class.
Thanks for any  help and guidance.

Oops , code in my post has " sign instead of #, not in the working program! Program runs fine except for problem with writing text to label.

Oops 2, all indentations are ok in the working program. the self.lbl2 has a wrong indentation here. My mistake, excuse me

Please check your indentation in show_mousepos. The two self.lbl2 ... lines are missing one level in your post and are consequently outside of the function, which might explain the issue.

Thanks for the remark but the code i pasted from notepad had different spacing I didn't see that error. The indentations are correct in my running program. I omitted lines to make the code block smaller.

Yes, I saw your "Oops 2" comment after a few hours. In case it was overlooked: There is another answer post by me that you didn't reply to yet.

You are calling Toplevel1.show_mousepos("") and the method is show_mousepos(self). You are effectively telling the program that "" is an instance of Toplevel1 and that you want to modify the attribute like "".lbl2['text'] = str(mdy). That does not work.
Do you create an instance of Toplevel1 somewhere in the code that you didn't post? You will need to use it there. Either as instance.show_mousepos() or as Toplevel1.show_mousepos(instance).

Edit, answering to the comment and new code.
You are creating your instance here
_w1 = BRC_ASSISTCURSOR_TEST2.Toplevel1(_top1)
This _w1 is the instance. In your mouse_data class you want to use it as
_w1.show_mousepos()
There are a couple more issues though. In your support file you use
global root and global _top1, _w1 (these mean getting access to a global variable), but you never defined those variables in the global namespace. If you really want to use globals here, you probably want to define them where you also do _debug. That section could look like this
_debug = True  # False to eliminate debug printing from callback functions.
root = None
_top1 = None
_w1 = None

Furthermore, I don't think your mouse_data class will work. You can adjust it to
@staticmethod
def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):

for your on_click definition. Also remove the trailing comma here global mdx,. Did you get the code as a sample from somewhere?
Finally, you never actually use the mouse_data class yet. You could use it at the end of the init of Toplevel1:
...
self.btnStop.place(relx=0.89, rely=0.841, height=26, width=57)
self.btnStop.configure(command=self.btnstop_click)

mouse_data()


Thanks for your help? I did not create an instance of left that code out.   When I write . Toplevel1.show_mousepos(self) gives an error.  I will try your suggestions. I still do not get grab on creating instances , how to do it and where to put those commands. !!

@FrancisDusselier
You need to create an instance of your class to properly use it. Somewhere in your code you want something like var_name = Toplevel1(). Then var_name is an instance of your Toplevel1 class and you can use the methods like var_name.btnstop_click() or var_name.show_mousepos().

Thanks aRTy again for your help. I added var_name=Toplevel1 ad the end of the Class Toplevel1 with one indent but gives error > name Toplevel1 not defined. Tried in the Class mouse_data gives also error on the var_name .  Do i have to declare the instance from Toplevel1 in the Toplevel1 class or in the mouse_data class or outside both . Do i have to declare the var_name also somewhere. It's is like a mystery to me..  I added all the code and the BRC_ASSISTCURSOR_support.py file also so it might be better to understand why it does not seem to work for me.

I edited/expanded my answer. I'm not sure if you get a notification for that, so I'm leaving this comment.

Thanks aRTy for explanation.  I want to add that I declared the instance var_name=Toplevel1() in and out of the classes, with indentation and no indentation all kind of errors appear as mentioned in above comment. Thanks again.
